# is where (A and B) and where (B and A) in SQL the same?

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I have a doubt that: Is `(A and B)` vs `(B and A)` is the same in terms of executing time in SQL?
Assuming I index (B, A) on my table and I query `where A and B`, does SQL know to look up for B condition first and then A to take advantage of indexing?
If not, I have to query `where B and A`, so it implied that A and B are different from B and A at SQL level?

Comment: "SQL" is a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Although i would say that no modern optimizer would treat them different, it's still important to know which DBMS product you are using, especially if it comes to index usage.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I use mysql, I also think it's the same but If so, does I query `where A and B` taking advantage of index(B, A)